# XmlSerializer and different field in class and xml attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

I have xml with several items, for example:

```
<TestObject>
  <TestElement1/>
  <TestElement2/>
</TestObject>
<TestObject>
  <TestElement1/>
  <TestElement2/>
</TestObject>
```

Also I have class:

```
class TestClass {
  public int TestElement1 { get; set; }
  public int Element { get; set; }
}
```

If I do:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestClass>));
List<TestClass> list = (List<TestClass>)s.Deserialize("myXml.xml");
```

After it I get list with objects TestClass, but property Element didn't set. How I must change serialization, if I want to set TestElement2 in Element field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decorate the `Element` property with an `[XmlElement]` attribute:

```
[XmlRoot("TestObject")]
class TestClass {
    public int TestElement1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TestElement2")]
    public int Element { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try XmlElement attribute

```
public class TaxRates{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxRate")]
    public decimal ReturnTaxRate;
}
```

see [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)